# Why can a float be an integer without throwing an exception?

Tags: java, types, primitive

Why does this throw an exception:

```
float var1 = 24.0;
System.out.print(var1);
```

But this doesn't:

```
float var1 = 24;
System.out.print(var1);
```

I understand that, in the first case, I'd need to include the "f" at the end of the number to distinguish it from a double. But I don't understand why the compiler doesn't have a problem with skipping the "f" if there is no decimal point. I thought that maybe Java was treating it like an int even though I'd declared the variable as a float, but `((Object)var1).getClass().getName()` results in `0java.lang.Float`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`24.0` is a `double` literal, and cannot be automatically (implicitly) converted to a `float`. `24` is an `int` literal, so what you see here is a [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) from an `int` to a `float`.